# R: Substituting missing values (NAs) with two different values

Tags: r, na, missing-data, recode

I might be overcomplicating things - would love to know if if there is an easier way to solve this. I have a data frame (df) with 5654 observations - 1332 are foreign-born, and 4322 Canada-born subjects.

The variable `df$YR_IMM` captures: "In what year did you come to live in Canada?" 
See the following distribution of observations per immigration year `table(df$YR_IMM)` :

```
1920 1926 1928 1930 1939 1942 1944 1946 1947 1948 1949 1950 1951 1952 1953 1954 
2    1    1    2    1    2    1    1    1    9    5    1    7   13    3    5 
1955 1956 1957 1958 1959 1960 1961 1962 1963 1964 1965 1966 1967 1968 1969 1970 
10    5    8    6    6    1    5    1    6    3    7   16   18   12   15   13 
1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986 
10   17    8   18   25   16   15   12   16   27   13   16   11    9   17   16 
1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003
24   21   31   36   26   30   26   24   22   30   29   26   47   52   53   28   9
```

Naturally these are only foreign-born individuals (mean = 1985) - however, 348 foreign-borns are missing. There are a total of 4670 NAs that also include Canada-borns subjects.

How can I code these `df$YR_IMM` NAs in such a way that

```
348 (NA) --> 1985
4322(NA) --> 100
```

Additionally, the status is given by `df$Brthcoun` with `0 = "born in Canada"` and `1 = "born outside of Canada`.

Hope this makes sense - thank you!

EDIT: This was the solution ->

df$YR_IMM[is.na(df$YR_IMM) & df$Brthcoun == 0] <- 100
df$YR_IMM[is.na(df$YR_IMM) & df$Brthcoun == 1] <- 1985

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to replace NAs with either the value `1985` or `100` based on another variable? What's the variable name?

Comment: Hello Aziz, I'm not replacing based on another variable. I'm trying to replace WITHIN the variable - as in recode the NAs  into 1985 or 100 . Does that make sense?

Comment: How do you want to decide *which* 348 NAs to replace by 1985?  Random selection? The first 348? ...?

Comment: My understanding is that you want to replace NAs with `1985` for foreign-born, and with `100` for Canada-born? If that's correct, what variable stores the foreign-/Canada-born status?

Comment: Thanks Aziz! Yes 100 would stand for "Canada-born". From my understanding it wouldn't affect my analyses if I choose to do a random selection of 348 NAs to be substituted with 1985. However, if you think it's better - the status is given by `df$Brthcoun` with `0 = "born in Canada"`  and `1 = "born outside of Canada"`

Comment: can you please edit your question to include the information in your last comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
df$YR_IMM[is.na(df$YR_IMM) & df$Brthcoun == 0] <- 100
df$YR_IMM[is.na(df$YR_IMM) & df$Brthcoun == 1] <- 1985
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you so much Joshua! this is exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: no problem.  glad I could help.  you should accept the edits to your original post so others do not have to read the entire thread.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should also work:

```
df$YR_IMM <- ifelse(is.na(df$YR_IMM) & df$Brthcoun == 0, 100, 1985)
```